# How can I switch two rows in a dataframe (Either randomly or specifically chosen)?

Tags: r

Good evening,

I would like to switch two randomly selected rows from a dataframe ("data_example").

```
set.seed(16) #for reproducible random generation
data_example<- data.frame(id=1:number, x =runif(number, max = xmax), y = runif(number, max = ymax))
swap <- [sample(nrow(data_example),2),]
```

This way I receive two randomly selected rows but I am failing at how to bet swap them. Can anybody help?

Thanks so much in advance and kind regards!

Comment: `number` , `xmax`, and `ymax` are missing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
swap2 <- function(x) {
  x <- max(x)
  while (length(table(ind <- sort(sample(x, size = 2)))) < 2) 1
  replace(seq_len(x), ind, rev(ind))
}
dat <- data.frame(id = seq_len(10), x = 0)
dat
#    id x
# 1   1 0
# 2   2 0
# 3   3 0
# 4   4 0
# 5   5 0
# 6   6 0
# 7   7 0
# 8   8 0
# 9   9 0
# 10 10 0
set.seed(42)
dat[swap2(nrow(dat)),]
#    id x
# 5   5 0  # <---
# 2   2 0
# 3   3 0
# 4   4 0
# 1   1 0  # <---
# 6   6 0
# 7   7 0
# 8   8 0
# 9   9 0
# 10 10 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is "ind" short for index?

Comment: Yes, not sure when/where I started using that. (Perhaps when colleagues complained about using `i` or `j`, more obscure variable names.)